# Replacing old sql written in asp.net with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I was trying to replace SQL code with LINQ in order to migrate in to MVC ,but i don't know how to use subquery in LINQ.As of now i have replaced inner sql query with LINQ,i would like to know how to do with outer query.

Following is the SQL query

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN Region_Code,
    R1.REGION_NAME 
FROM
    GP_REGION 
    INNER JOIN GP_REGION R1 ON GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN = R1.REGION_CODE 
WHERE
    GP_REGION.REGION_HAS_DATA = 'Y'
    AND
    GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN IN 
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT AR.BRANCH_CODE 
        FROM
            PORTAL.UA_APPLN_ROLE AR 
            INNER JOIN PORTAL.UA_GROUP G ON AR.GROUP_CODE = G.GROUP_CODE
        WHERE
            G.USER_ID = '" + Global.UserId() + "' AND AR.APPLICATION_ID = '" + ApplicationId + "'
     )
 ORDER BY
     GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN
```

Here the inner query i have replaced as shown below by using following LINQ

```
var regions = from p in db3.UA_APPLN_ROLE.AsEnumerable()
              join i in db3.UA_GROUP.AsEnumerable()
                  on p.GROUP_CODE equals i.GROUP_CODE
              where
                  i.USER_ID == Global.UserId()
                  &&
                  p.APPLICATION_ID == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"]

              select new
              {
                  branchcode = p.BRANCH_CODE
              };
```

But i would like to know the outer sql query how can i replace and join with existing LINQ code i wrote

Comment: FYI: using `AsEnumerable()` will result in all the data from both tables being fetched from the DB, then the querying will be done in your code.  Don't use `AsEnumerable()` unless you need to do something that cannot be translated to SQL by your Linq query provider.

Comment: Linq and Entity Framework has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. You shouldn't be using EF Models as ViewModels anyway. There is nothing stopping you from continuing to use your existing database code with ASP.NEt MVC.

Comment: Replacing sql queries with linq will make your application slower as your linq code will be replaced by loops once compiled. When the sql queries are formated correctly, they can be way faster than than anything you can do in code.

Comment: @Fjodr, I think you are wrong. The LINQ to SQL engine makes use of the SQL optimizer and in most cases will write better queries than most of inexperienced SQL programmers. This is provided you use LINQ correctly(unlike AsEnumerable above)

Comment: @AmmarCSE Right. I thought it was about taking the whole table and filtering with LINQ. I don't know much about LINQ to SQL. I think that it is not specified in the question neither.

Answer (score 1):

You combine the subquery into the main query as follows:

```
  var efQuery = from gp in db3.GP_REGION
                join r1 in db3.GP_REGION on gp.REGION_MAIN equals r1.REGION_CODE 
                where regions.Contains(gp.REGION_MAIN)
                   && gp.REGION_HAS_DATA = "Y"
                select new
                {
                    Region_Code = gp.REGION_MAIN,
                    Region_Name = r1.REGION_NAME 
                };
  var queryResult = efQuery.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Region_Code);
```

You can speed the processing up a bit by using `.AsNoTracking()`, e.g. `db3.GP_REGION.AsNoTracking()`.

In general it's a good idea to monitor the generated SQL query to avoid situations where it looks simple in code, but is transformed into bad SQL.

But in my opinion the advantages of having the query a first class member in your code (compared to SQL in strings) outweigh the sometimes non-intuitive generated SQL.